# Problem in finding appropriate model

Tags: econometrics

I'm having a problem in deciding which model to be used in our research report. The main focus of our research is to find out the effect on export using CPI, output, area. The thing is, we have a negative number in CPI data, so we won't use log log or lin log model. What confuse me is that is the log-lin model usable in this case? After I done the test with eview, there goes something like this :

```
Dependent Variable: LOG(EXPORT)             
Method: Least Squares               
Date: 05/10/16   Time: 23:27                
Sample: 1995 2014               
Included observations: 20               

Variable Coefficient    Std. Error  t-Statistic Prob.  

C       5.948313    1.766788    3.366738    0.0039
AREA    9.70E-05    0.000285    0.339960    0.7383
CPI     0.000955    0.009119    0.104687    0.9179
OUTPUT  4.89E-05    1.34E-05    3.651207    0.0022

R-squared           0.809360        Mean dependent var      8.413843
Adjusted R-squared  0.773615        S.D. dependent var      0.345174
S.E. of regression  0.164234        Akaike info criterion  -0.598198
Sum squared resid   0.431562        Schwarz criterion      -0.399052
Log likelihood      9.981983        Hannan-Quinn criter.   -0.559323
F-statistic         22.64257        Durbin-Watson stat      1.331386
Prob(F-statistic)   0.000005
```

Sorry for the format, but the coefficients are extremely small in this test. However, its R squared and Adjusted R-squared are actually larger than the one in lin - lin model. So is it possible for us to choose this log-lin over lin-lin model?
P/s : The data will then be used for T test and F test, if that matters. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this you need to look at the residuals after you run each model to determine whether log transformation is needed at all. There is not enough info on data structure so it's hard to comment. If you have a time series structure then there are a host of other things you need to check for like serial correlation for example. If it's a panel then a bunch of different issues need to be addressed. Finally, there are specification tests out there whuch may guide you with picking the right model.